# Angular 2 - ngIf of observable makes element unaccesible

Tags: angular

I'm trying to run some DOM manipulation code when an observable resolves and an ngIf conditional is therefore resolved in the view, but every time I'm trying to access it, it returns undefined. Here is a snapshot of my code:

View:

```
<div *ngIf="data?.data_child" id="data-element">
    ... data here
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public data;
constructor(private _async: AsyncService){}

ngOnInit() {
    this._async.subscribe( result => {
        if( result ) {
            // data contains data_child
            this.data = result;

            // run DOM manipulation on the element
            if( this.data.data_child ) {

               // error is thrown here as the element is undefined
               $('#data-element').scrollTop($('#data-element')[0].scrollHeight);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to mention that I have tried creating another subscription inside ngAfterViewInit and calling it there but still, the same error occurs.

The only thing that kind of worked was emitting an event when the data is loaded which I then subscribe to and trigger the DOM manipulation methods. However, it only works the first time ngOnInit is triggered as further routing to that component no longer trigger the event( there is no reuseComponent functionality ).

I also tried to use @ViewChild and set a template variable which is then used in the controller, but it's still throwing the same error.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: you can use resolvers to have all the data in the component before the template is loaded.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this subject a bit more as I'm not familiar with them? I only have access to the data I need to fetch after I'm subscribing to the activatedRoute parameters and queryParameters which I use to build the url. Would I be able to use a resolver in this case?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html google how to use. But basically what you would do is put your requests in this class and in the module you say you need to resolve the resolver before going into component so when the component loads the data will already be there. Otherwise you have to find a workaround and set time outs etc.

Comment: Thank you! I have managed to do it using a Resolver, however the Observable has to be completed for it to actually resolv. I guess I will have to query additional data in the actual component?

Comment: no problem. You would query the data you need from the resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook to manipulate DOM elements. Are you using jQuery to just get the height of the element? You can do that using native Angular code: `this.elementRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight`.

jQuery should be used with caution, but if you have to use it you could make a directive which use `#data-element` as its selector:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any

@Directive({
  selector: '#data-element'
})
export class DataElementDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).scrollTop($('#data-element')[0].scrollHeight);
  }

}
```

But again there should be no need to resort to jQuery for this kind of thing.

Comment: I tried using the elementRef as well inside the ngAfterViewInit, but it throws the error that nativeElement is not found on undefined, which is because of that observable and ngIf

Comment: I think you should post a Plunkr, I have a feeling there is a more straight forward solution to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer! I will dwelve into directives soon, they seem pretty handy. I solved my issue using a Resolver instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the change detection a chance to detect something first and the rendering to happen.

The moment you set `this.data = result;` your change detection will kick in and will order a rerendering of the affected view ( /-child ). This will take way longer then it takes to evaluate your next `if` case which means at the moment you call your `jQuery` function the `DOM Element` isn't accessible yet.

A quick and dirty solution would be to use `setTimeout`:

```
this.data = result;

if( this.data.data_child ) {
    setTimeout(() => {
         $('#data-element').scrollTop($('#data-element')[0].scrollHeight);
    });
}
```

You can use this in your example, but i should mention that this isn't considered a good practice.

A better approach would probably be to use maybe an `Observable` which will notify you when your data has been assigned or through another kind of logic, for example set a fixed anchor you want to scroll to, which doesn't rely on dynamically added elements and scroll to that instead.

On the other hand, to imitate events like scrollTo, focus, blur on dynamically generated elements are often tricky if you want to trigger them programmatically and want to do it the "angular" way. Speaking of which, a directive which serves as a container for your data could be another good way to implement things like this without using timeouts.

Comment: The good'ol $timeout is back. Unfortunately, this doesn't do the trick as the element is still not found( not sure when ngIf enables it but it takes its time ). The Observable approach is pretty much the same as using an EventEmitter, which I did try but it only triggers once. 

I'm trying to keep everything as 'by-the-book' as possible, which is why I stay away from hacky solutions such as the setTimeout. The Directive solution sounds like it would work, however I have never used them in Angular 2 yet.

Answer (score 0):

First you absolutely should use ViewChild, rather than JQuery.

```
<div #data-element>
    ... data here
</div>
```

in the template and

```
@ViewChild('data-element') dataElement;
```

in the code behind. Angular is an all encompassing framework. You really kind of have to embrace it and it's way of doing things. There is, of course, a learning curve, but it's well worth it, and there's not a lot, JQuery can add to it.

Don't forget to add 'ViewChild' to your imports directive. e.g.

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, OnChanges, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
```

However, because the element is toggled with ngIf, you'll still get the same error, because the element doesn't exist when the component is initialised, so the view child is created with an undefined ElementRef.

There are a few solutions.

If you running Angular 8, you can simply tell it that the element is not static and when it exists the view child will receive the ElementRef:

```
@ViewChild('data-element', { static: false }) dataElement: ElementRef;
```

Prior to Angular 8, the best way is to place the conditional element in a child component, and pass any required data in as a input parameters:

```
<app-data-element *ngIf="data?.data_child"> </app-data-element>
```

with the the child component rendering your data. You can pass your data into it via @input parameters:

```
@input() data: DataStructure;
@input() dob: Date;
```

You can also pass data back via @Output events.

```
@Output() dataChanged: EventEmitter<DataStructure> = new EventEmitter<DataStructure>();
this.dataChanged.emit(data);
```

The element always exists in the child component so the ElementRef will always be valid.

And finally, you could also just toggle the style display property instead. The component always exists in the DOM and the view child will always have a valid ElementRef. Obviously it always uses resources and contributes to load overhead, where you ever display it or not:

```
<div [style.display] = "displayData()" id="data-element">
    ... data here
</div>
```

With your code behind being something like:

```
@ViewChild('data-element') dataElement;

public displayData() {
    if (data?.data_child) {
       return 'block';
    }
    return 'none';
}
```

(This will work with JQuery selectors as well, but you really shouldn't.)